# Alias for gnome-open to open different files

Tags: gnome, bash, bashrc, alias

I want to make alias for `gnome-open` so I be able to open files with command `opn somefile.doc`
How can I pass filename with this alias?

Comment: ? simply by adding `alias opn=gnome-open` to your `bashrc`. It then takes the file as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your ~/.bash_aliases:

```
alias opn='gnome-open'
```